# show data stored in localstorage to another page

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am working with the user authentication in jquery mobile and phonegapp. First i POST the username and password to the server and if success it return some data that are stored in the local-storage.

**Here the $ajax post**

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: "json",
    url: KPSCtuts.Settings.Url,
    data:"username=" + userName + "&password=" + password + "&login=",
    success: function (resp) {

        $.mobile.loading("hide");

        if (resp.success === true) {

            // Create session. 
            var today = new Date();
            var expirationDate = new Date();
            expirationDate.setTime(today.getTime() + KPSCtuts.Settings.sessionTimeoutInMSec);
            KPSCtuts.Session.getInstance().set({
                userProfileModel: resp.userProfileModel,
                userId: resp.userId,
                userName: resp.userName,
                sessionId: resp.sessionId,
                expirationDate: expirationDate,
                keepSignedIn:me.$chkKeepSignedIn.is(":checked")
            }); 
            // Go to main menu.
            $.mobile.navigate(me.mainMenuPageId);
            return;
        } else {
            if (resp.extras.msg) {


                        me.$ctnErr.html("<p>"+resp.extras.msg+"</p>");
                        me.$ctnErr.addClass("bi-ctn-err").slideDown();

            }
        }
    },
    error: function (e) {
        $.mobile.loading("hide");
        console.log(e.message);
        // TODO: Use a friendlier error message below.
        me.$ctnErr.html("<p>1-Oops! KPSCtuts had a problem and could not log you on.  Please try again in a few minutes.</p>");
        me.$ctnErr.addClass("bi-ctn-err").slideDown();
    }
});
```

here the session.js that is setting the localstorage data using JSON.stringify.

```
var KPSCtuts = KPSCtuts || {};
KPSCtuts.Session = (function () {
var instance;

function init() {

    var sessionIdKey = "KPSCtuts-session";

    return {
        // Public methods and variables.
        set: function (sessionData) {
            window.localStorage.setItem(sessionIdKey, JSON.stringify(sessionData));
        },

        get: function () {

            var result = null;

            try {
                result = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem(sessionIdKey));
            } catch(e){}

            return result;
        }
    };
};

return {
    getInstance: function () {
        if (!instance) {
            instance = init();
        }
        return instance;
    }
};
}());
```

here the O/P of the localstorage

```
KPSCtuts-session:{"userProfileModel":"Abhilash","userId":"1","userName":"abhilashrajrs","sessionId":"usr_b0424c8b16","expirationDate":"2016-03-23T19:16:16.319Z","keepSignedIn":true}
```

I want the Name of user to show on another page, how i can pull the data from the local-storage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should work.

`var userName = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('KPSCtuts-session'))['userName'];`

Here, you can use the variable userName.

Comment: Perfect @Harin Kommuri

Comment: I have one more doubt can u help me.
Is there a way to pull server date and time to jquerymobile phonegap app

Comment: Sry. I have no idea.

Comment: Raj best you create a new question related to server time to your phonegap client. If you have access to the server, then it should not be a problem.